# If the thread calling `pthread_join ()` is canceled, then the target thread will remain joinable

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

From: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join

> If the thread calling pthread_join() is canceled, then the target thread will remain joinable (i.e., it will not be detached).

Does this mean that the target threads will not get aborted if we cancel the main thread calling `pthread_join`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_join()` doesn't 'abort' a target thread in the first place, so I'm not sure if I fully  understand the question.

Basically, if a thread (the main thread or otherwise) calls `pthread_join()` it is asking to block until the target thread has exited. In the normal case, once the target thread has exited,the thread that called `pthread_join()` will unblock and any resources that were associated witht he target thread can be freed by the system.

However, if a thread has called `pthread_join()` (and is blocked waiting for the target thread to exit) and the blocked thread gets cancelled, then essentially nothing happens to the target of the `pthread_join()` call (it continues on).  What the docs are clarifying is that that thread remains 'joinable' - which means:

- another thread can call `pthread_join()` to wait for it to finish
- the resources that the system can release when a thread completes and is joined will *not* be released unless another thread joins the target thread or `pthread_detach()` is called for the target thread.  calling `pthread_detach()` for a thread makes it 'unjoinable' - it continues running and it's resources will get freed when it exits (the detach call indicates to the system that nothing will use those resources after the thread exits), but no thread can join it anymore.

Comment: *"pthread_join() doesn't 'abort' a target thread in the first place, "* I didn't say that it does. If we don't write the pthread_join, the child threads will get aborted if the parent does. so, I asked if we cancel the parent thread calling pthread_join, will the child  get aborted?

Comment: *"the resources that the system can release when a thread completes "* What kind of resources would they be? Like - memory locations malloced ?

Comment: @Anisha: just to be clear (for other readers or whoever), there is no child/parent relationship among threads. If a thread A creates thread B then thread A exits (or is cancelled), there's no effect on thread B. Of course, it's another story if the process exits.

Comment: @Anisha: I'm not sure exactly, but the kinds of things that might be freed when a thread exits (and it's no longer joinable) could include: the stack for the thread, a memory location where the value 'returned' by the thread in `pthread_exit()` is kept unitl joined, and there must be some sort of synchronization object (something like a condition variable) that a thread can block on when it calls `pthread_join()` to wait for the target thread to exit.

Answer (score 0):

What the statement literary mean is that if you have 3 threads `A`,`B`, `C` and `B` joins `A`, then `C` is able to join `A` if `B` is cancelled.

Canceling the joining thread doesn't not abort necessarily the thread which is joined. When a thread is cancelled, it can operate a cleanup before termination, and this include cancelling other threads.